# Why does Hugging Face's push_to_hub convert saved models to .bin instead of using safetensor mode?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, llama

I am attempting to push a saved model in `model-00001-of-00006.safetensors` mode, but the model gets converted to `pytorch_model-00001-of-00006.bin` before being saved to the hub.

How can I prevent this?

Here is what I am simply doing:

```
model.push_to_hub('chukypedro/' + new_model, use_temp_dir=False)
tokenizer.push_to_hub('chukypedro/' + new_model, use_temp_dir=False)
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HWHN.png)

```
model.push_to_hub('chukypedro/' + new_model, use_temp_dir=False)
tokenizer.push_to_hub('chukypedro/' + new_model, use_temp_dir=False)
```

I am expecting the model to be pushed in safetensors mode.

Comment: FYI, I uploaded a model in the .bin format. Some days after, I got an automatic PR to convert my model to .safetensors. So if that's what you want, maybe it should fix itself in a few days

Comment: @SilentCloud that is what I want, but my model has been on huggingface for two weeks now, and no pull request to convert to safetensors.

Comment: Maybe you could find help on their forums, they are usually responsive. I'm sorry I can't help much

Comment: @SilentCloud Thanks a lot, I have been able to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

For any one encountering the same problem, convert your model using the below link after making a push to hugging face.

https://huggingface.co/spaces/safetensors/convert